# Как сделать что бы при вызове клавиатуры было видно только определённые элементы?

Tags: android

Такая проблема, имеется страница в мобильном приложении
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

При нажатии на EditText появляется клавиатура которая перекрывает кнопку записаться
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как сделать что бы при появлении клавиатуры было видно и кнопку и поле ввода?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Сейчас в Manifest для данной activity прописано `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"`

xml код для данной страницы:

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 

    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp">

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent">

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/DataPick"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/linearLayout2"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <ImageButton
                        android:id="@+id/imageButton"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="start"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                        android:backgroundTint="#FAFAFA"
                        android:clickable="true"
                        android:src="@drawable/back"
                        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="horizontal">


                    <ImageButton
                        android:id="@+id/OtherAvtoMoyTV"
                        android:layout_width="45dp"
                        android:layout_height="45dp"
                        android:layout_gravity="right"
                        android:backgroundTint="@color/projectOrange"
                        android:scaleType="fitXY"
                        android:src="@drawable/map_spot"
                        app:itemIconTint="@drawable/bottom_record_colors"></ImageButton>
                </LinearLayout>
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/linearLayout2"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="53dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/editTextComment"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/DataPick">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="120dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="Интервал начала"></TextView>

                    <Spinner
                        android:id="@+id/IntervalStart"
                        android:layout_width="160dp"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"></Spinner>
                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="100dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="Время записи" />

                    <Spinner
                        android:id="@+id/TimeRecord"
                        android:layout_width="160dp"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:layout_marginTop="10dp" />

                </LinearLayout>
            </LinearLayout>

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/editTextComment"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="150dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
                android:background="@drawable/comment_edit"
                android:gravity="top|left"
                android:hint="Введите коментарий по желанию"
                android:inputType="textCapSentences|textMultiLine"
                android:lines="8"
                android:minHeight="200dp"
                android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                android:paddingTop="10dp"
                android:paddingRight="10dp"
                android:paddingBottom="10dp"
                android:scrollbars="vertical"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/linearLayout"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/linearLayout2" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/linearLayout3"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:text="Время мойки"
                    android:textAlignment="textEnd" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/TimeTVFin"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:textAlignment="textStart"
                    android:textColor="@color/projectOrange" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/linearLayout3"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/linearLayout">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:text="Итого"
                    android:textAlignment="textEnd" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/PriceTVFin"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:textAlignment="textStart"
                    android:textColor="@color/projectOrange" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/recordButtonMain"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="60dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
                android:backgroundTint="@color/projectOrange"
                android:fontFamily="@font/roboto"
                android:onClick="nextButtonMain_onClick"
                android:text="Записаться"
                android:textAllCaps="false"
                android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/linearLayout3" />
        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
    </ScrollView>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: @Andrew, я же написал что пробовал этот способ

Comment: можно так же в onCreate() добавить строки:
`getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_VISIBLE|WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_RESIZE);`

Comment: @Andrew, я так понимаю это эквивалентно android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"?

Comment: в некоторых источниках советуют его использовать вместе :)

Comment: @Andrew, просто в моём случае android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize" работает, но проблема в том что появляется только EditText , а надо что бы и EditText и Button. Как я понимаю android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize" "Наводится" на тот элемент у которого фокус

Comment: а в чем логика размещения в constraint в котором scrollView внутри которого constraint?) сделайте родителем scrollView может проблема в разметке?

Comment: кроме того ConstraintLayout специально разработан для одноуровневой верстки и все эти вложенные в него LinearLayout это печаль ... Вложить в констрайнт еще контейнеров, это огромное время прорисовки экрана. может вы этого не замечаете, но устройству от этого не легче. Сетка верстки в дизайне андроид - 16dp, все эти 10, 20, 45, 53 dp тоже печаль конечно